# Drupal 7 Feeds - how to map custom taxonomy field as target in node processor?

Tags: drupal, mapping, taxonomy, feed

I have a taxonomy vocabulary named "Counties". In that vocabulary I add new field "ISO-id".
In my CSV file I have column of "ISO-id"'s.
I create content type with field which point to "Counties" taxonomy.
When I try to map target for "ISO-id" in feed importer, I can only find "Counties" but no "ISO-id" in target selector.
Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using a 'Node processor' in your importer. You must change it to 'Taxonomy term processor':

1. Go to admin/structure/feeds and 'Add importer' (ex: 'term import')
2. 'Edit' the new importer you created.
3. Set 'Fetcher' to 'File Upload'
4. Set 'Parser' to 'CSV'
5. IMPORTANT! Set 'Processor' to 'Taxonomy term processor'
   [image: Inside Processor, select the option 'Taxonomy term processor']
6. Under Processor, go to 'Settings', select the right vocabulary, in your case "Counties".
7. Under Processor, go to 'Mapping', Voila! Now you can set the target to the field you add to that vocabulary, there must be "ISO-id" in the list box.

Answer (score 0):

Target means the vocabulary in drupal....so your target should be 'Counties'. I don't have feeds set up on an installation to test here, but you should select select counties, and then add "ISO-id" as the source.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for can be done using [Feeds Tamper](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) and [Feeds Tamper: Search term by field](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper_stbf).

The combination of those modules will allow Feeds to search in a taxonomy term field for the value being imported. It will then use the taxonomy term which has a matching field.